# Symfony2 cant access app_dev.php unless removing .htacess file in web folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony

Symfony2 cant access app_dev.php unless removing .htacess file in web folder, I would appreciate if any one would help me out here thank you in advance.

Content of the .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$ 
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1] 
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$ 
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L] 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f 
    RewriteRule .? - [L] 
    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L] 
</IfModule> 
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c> 
    <IfModule mod_alias.c> 
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/ # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead 
    </IfModule> 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What exactly happens when you access the site? Did you get a message like "You are not allowed to access this file. Check ..."?

Comment: no it was like "Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log." and also I am unable to see web directory in the Index of  list.

Comment: Can you provide the content of your .htaccess file please.

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
  
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]
   
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]
    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>       
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you consider [the "Configuring a web server" part of the symfony book](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html#apache2)?

Excerpt:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.tld
    ServerAlias www.domain.tld

    DocumentRoot /var/www/project/web
    <Directory /var/www/project/web>
        # enable the .htaccess rewrites
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/project_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/project_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The `AllowOverride All` statement is important here. If this is missing then you aren't allowed to define rules in .htaccess files.